# Error upon Cloud Function for Firebase deployment

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been trying to deploy a Cloud Function to my Firebase project.
It's my first time doing so, also my first time programming with JavaScript.

Here's my code in Node.JS:

```
'use strict'
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const firebaseTriggers = functions.region('europe-west1').firestore;
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.postNotification = firebaseTriggers
      .document('/post notifications/{notificatioId}').onWrite((snap, context) => {
      const notifcationRecieverId = snap.data().mReciever;
      const payload = {
        data: {
            notification_type: 'POST',
            title: snap.data().mTitle,
            body: snap.data().mDescription,
            sender_id: snap.data().mSender,
            reciever_id: snap.data().mReciever,
            notification_id: context.params.notificatioId
        }
      };
      return db.collection('dog owners')
        .document(notifcationRecieverId)
        .get()
        .then(recieverDoc => {
            console.log('Retrieving FCM tokens');
            const tokens = recieverDoc.data().mTokens;
            console.log('Sending notification payload');
            return admin.message().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
        });
});
```

Upong deployment, I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Can someone help me understand why?

Comment: On Stack Overflow please don't use pictures of text.  It's better to copy the text into the question so it's easier to read and search.  We should not have to click away to see all relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you have got space in your colleciton name. This is bad convetion.

`post notifications` => `postNotifications`